# Can win11 install Ros2?

Tags: windows, installation, ros2

I want to learn Ros2, I have tried to install ubuntu and win 10 but both failed to recognize my RTX 3050. I tried running a virtual machine and it didn't get any better. I don't know if I can install Ros2 on Win 11. Please help me

Comment: You could try to install it, but right now Windows10 is the most recent Windows OS that is supported.

Comment: Can you give more details about what errors you ran into on each of the environments you did attempt to install it on?

Answer (score 2):

I just successfully installed ros 2 (galactic) on windows 11 (in so far as I am able to run the `demo_nodes_cpp talker` and `listener`).

I initially tried following instructions on the official page and ran into a number of unclear issues (command not found, python version issues etc.) that felt like it was going to be a waste of time, until I went through that alternative:
https://ms-iot.github.io/ROSOnWindows/GettingStarted/SetupRos2.html

It was surprisingly painless.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe wsl on Win11 will help you a lot.
You can install a wsl Ubuntu22.04 in MS store, then you can launch it in terminal of Windows. And WSL can share the resources on Windows, possibly including your RTX. The WSL is not like vitual machine, as you can even get GUI from it.

However, I think the reason why your OS cannot recognize your RTX3050 is that you have not install the driver for it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).